# Loading another image with data-rel inside a div tag

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to change from a loading image to display a chart. I've never used the data-rel attribute before, so I am confused on how to word this question properly, perhaps the code I have will explain it:

`<div id="chk_all" style="width: 320px; height: 260px; background: url(/inquire/images/wait.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;" data-rel="/inquire/?action=gchd&prj=1119&tp=chk&stp=0&cht=pie"></div>`

This is what I have to make the chart:

`<?php
 '<div id="iss_part" class="ov_chart_iss" style="width: 320px; height: 260px;" data-rel="' .  Helpers::buildURL(array('action' => SiteMap::CHART_GET_DATA, Defaults::PROJECT => $prj['id'],
Defaults::TYPEOFDATA => Defaults::ISSUE, Defaults::SUBTYPEOFDATA => 1,
Defaults::CHART_TYPE => Defaults::CHART_TYPE_COLUMN)) .'"></div>; ?>'`

This code displays the previous div tag I posted, if it helps, here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpg5G.png and this is what I have currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yePnt.png

Basically, I am trying to load what is in the data-rel attribute instead of it staying on the wait.gif image. Does this make any sense, and if so, how would I change this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a plugin of some kind?

Comment: No, I am using my own php code to handle this.

Comment: You need to give us more information (and tag your question more thoroughly). We have no idea what's generating your chart or what the `data-references` means.

Comment: I edited my post and added images to better explain. data-* is an html5 attribute...

Comment: um, was that sarcastic? If so, you don't need to be, I'm just trying to ask a question...

Answer (score 0):

## new way

```
<div id="chk_all" style="width: 320px; height: 260px; background: url(/inquire/images/wait.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;" data-rel='http://path.pointing.to.chart.com/inquire ...'></div>

// JS
var chkDiv = document.getElementById('#chk_all'),
    data = chkDiv.dataset;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "path/to/thing"+data.rel, true);
req.send("");

req.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return;
  chkDiv.style.background = '';
  chkDiv.innerHTML = x.responseText;
};
```

does this work for you? Haven't tested but in theory, should work.

Hope it helps.